# wxWidgets 2.9.4 built under Visual C++ Express 2010 gives unresolved external errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I have been trying to upgrade to wxWidgets 2.9.4 over my old 2.8.12 and have run into problems. I compiled it without errors from the command line but when I try to use them in the program that worked just fine under the previous version I get unresolved externals. I cut it down to just a bare frame and TextCtrl object and it still does this (it's basically identical to one of the sample codes at the moment).

I tried the following commands to build the static libraries:

1. nmake -f makefile.vc SHARED=0 BUILD=release + nmake -f makefile.vc SHARED=0 BUILD=debug
2. nmake -f makefile.vc SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 BUILD=release + nmake -f makefile.vc SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 BUILD=debug
3. nmake -f makefile.vc SHARED=0 BUILD=release UNICODE=0 + nmake -f makefile.vc SHARED=0 BUILD=debug UNICODE=0
4. nmake -f makefile.vc SHARED=0 BUILD=release UNICODE=0 MONOLITHIC=0 + nmake -f makefile.vc SHARED=0 BUILD=debug UNICODE=0 MONOLITHIC=0

Note that I tried using them with both the recommended unicode and no longer supported non-unicode (changed the project properties in Configuration Properties->General accordingly). Also, I used multi-threaded DLL /MD and /MDd linking as recommended by the wxWidgets manual.

Edit: Tried using \MT and \MTd as well, same effect.

From all of the above I get the same linker errors listed below when compiling my application. Please advise me what to do because I have ran out of ideas...

Additionally, as a final resort I built the whole thing using the converted MSVS project from the ../build/msw folder but it gave me the same results.

**Debug compile**

```
1>hworld.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall wxApp::Initialize(int &,unsigned short * *)" (?Initialize@wxApp@@UAE_NAAHPAPAG@Z)
1>hworld.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall wxAppConsoleBase::OnAssertFailure(unsigned short const *,int,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *)" (?OnAssertFailure@wxAppConsoleBase@@UAEXPBGH000@Z)
1>hworld.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall wxAppConsoleBase::OnAssert(unsigned short const *,int,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *)" (?OnAssert@wxAppConsoleBase@@UAEXPBGH00@Z)
1>hworld.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned short const * const wxEmptyString" (?wxEmptyString@@3PBGB)
1>hworld.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: static struct wxString::SubstrBufFromType<class wxScopedCharTypeBuffer<unsigned short> > __cdecl wxString::ConvertStr(char const *,unsigned int,class wxMBConv const &)" (?ConvertStr@wxString@@CA?AU?$SubstrBufFromType@V?$wxScopedCharTypeBuffer@G@@@1@PBDIABVwxMBConv@@@Z) referenced in function "private: static class wxScopedCharTypeBuffer<unsigned short> __cdecl wxString::ImplStr(char const *,class wxMBConv const &)" (?ImplStr@wxString@@CA?AV?$wxScopedCharTypeBuffer@G@@PBDABVwxMBConv@@@Z)
1>hworld.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl wxOnAssert(char const *,int,char const *,char const *,unsigned short const *)" (?wxOnAssert@@YAXPBDH00PBG@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall wxControlContainerBase::SetContainerWindow(class wxWindow *)" (?SetContainerWindow@wxControlContainerBase@@QAEXPAVwxWindow@@@Z)
1>wxpngd.lib(wxpng_pngread.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _inflateInit_ referenced in function _png_create_read_struct_2
1>wxpngd.lib(wxpng_pngread.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _inflate referenced in function _png_read_row
1>wxpngd.lib(wxpng_pngrutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _inflate
1>wxpngd.lib(wxpng_pngread.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _inflateEnd referenced in function _png_read_destroy
1>wxpngd.lib(wxpng_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _crc32 referenced in function _png_reset_crc
1>wxpngd.lib(wxpng_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _inflateReset referenced in function _png_reset_zstream
1>wxpngd.lib(wxpng_pngrutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _inflateReset
1>wxpngd.lib(wxpng_pngwrite.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflate referenced in function _png_write_flush
1>wxpngd.lib(wxpng_pngwutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _deflate
1>wxpngd.lib(wxpng_pngwrite.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflateEnd referenced in function _png_write_destroy
1>wxpngd.lib(wxpng_pngwutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _deflateEnd
1>wxpngd.lib(wxpng_pngwutil.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflateInit2_ referenced in function _png_zlib_claim
1>wxpngd.lib(wxpng_pngwutil.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflateReset referenced in function _png_zlib_release
```

**Release compile**

1>wxpng.lib(wxpng_png.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _crc32
1>wxpng.lib(wxpng_png.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _inflateReset
1>wxpng.lib(wxpng_pngrutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _inflateReset
1>wxpng.lib(wxpng_pngread.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol *inflateInit*
1>wxpng.lib(wxpng_pngread.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _inflate
1>wxpng.lib(wxpng_pngrutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _inflate
1>wxpng.lib(wxpng_pngread.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _inflateEnd
1>wxpng.lib(wxpng_pngwrite.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _deflate
1>wxpng.lib(wxpng_pngwutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _deflate
1>wxpng.lib(wxpng_pngwrite.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _deflateEnd
1>wxpng.lib(wxpng_pngwutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _deflateEnd
1>wxpng.lib(wxpng_pngwutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol *deflateInit2*
1>wxpng.lib(wxpng_pngwutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _deflateReset
1>MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _main

Answer (score 1):

All errors coming from libpng are due to not linking with `wxzlib[d].lib`, simply add it to the list of libraries in your project. Or use the recommended way to build wxWidgets projects with MSVC and use auto-linking by prepending `-I$(WXWIN)/include/msvc` to your compiler header files search path.

The rest of the errors (which you only get in debug build which is suspicious on its own) are due to a mismatch between ANSI and Unicode builds. I don't know which version do you use finally as you seem to have built all of them at one moment or the other but if you use the default build, then you need to have `_UNICODE` and/or `UNICODE` defined in your project options.

Finally, to avoid such build mismatches in the future, either do `nmake -f makefile.vc clean` or use different build directories by using unique `COMPILER_PREFIX` for each build in the future. This is really not rocket science, you just need to avoid confusing yourself by doing too many things at once. Good luck!

Comment: I had the wxzlibd.lib included and _UNICODE specified in C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor definitions. Here's the content of that cell which I got from one of the samples: "WIN32
_DEBUG
_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1
_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS=1
_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1
__WXMSW__
_UNICODE
_WINDOWS
NOPCH"

Comment: I will keep your advice to compiling in mind, thanks! Still, right now I have one project running and the other not with the same set of libraries I built...

Comment: Sorry, that's quite impossible. If one project links and the other does not, they can't use the same options. Anyhow, debugging linking problems is not hard: you can use `dumpbin` tool to find out where each symbol is referenced and the library in which it's defined. Next you just need to ensure this library is included and found.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project's settings and change General -> Character Set property accordingly. If you compiled the wx libs with UNICODE=0 (however recommended value is 1) then you need to use `Multi-Byte Character set`. If compiled ith UNICODE=1 then set that property to `Unicode`

As for runtime libs, if you compiled with SHARED=0 then in your project settings you will need to use C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Libraries property with 'Multi-Threaded Debug' and 'Multi-Threaded' for Debug and Release build accordingly.

The easiest way is to build wxWidgets libs from Visual Studio (there is a build/msw folder which contains solution file for VS2010) and in your project set the same properties as wx libs projects have.

Comment: Qote from my question: "Note that I tried using them with both the recommended unicode and no longer supported non-unicode (changed the project properties in Configuration Properties->General accordingly)". I tried using \MT and \MTd, same result (or lack thereof)...

Comment: But what about character set properties? As far as I can see, first piece of build log shows that there are problems with mthods which use char* so should be related to character set. Also have you tried to build from VS and then set the same compiler and lonker settings?

Comment: I set the character set to unicode for libraries with the "u" and to not set and multi-byte for the ones without the "u".

Comment: For linker settings I used one of my previous projects using the older wxWidgets version and adapted it the way I thought was correct (apparently it wasn't). Last night I managed to get one of the fresh sample codes to run, I'll compare the two, pinpoint what was wrong and post here. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I honestly have no idea what is wrong with my old project.. I copied contents of every tab in the project properties to match those of the sample and it still won't work. However, if I paste my code into the sample it will run just fine. Conclusion: there is something else with the dependencies I am missing and I have no idea what. It's good that I can get back to writing my program but it would still be nice to know what I have done wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I solved it by changing the setting in:

```
 C/C++ | Language | Treat WChar_t as built in type
```

to Yes.